# Gazebo image topic encoding

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having problems with the image topics published by Gazebo. A simple check with rviz or image_view yields that somethings wrong with the "encoding" field of the Image message.

I tried to modify this line in the robot urdf I'm using but it turned out after a bit of checking the logs that it does not really do anything with the field no matter if it's set to rgb8 or bgr8.

```
<xacro:stereo_camera_v0 parent="head_2_link" name="stereo" focal_length="3    57.95" hfov="85" image_format="rgb8" image_width="656" image_height="492" >

Error parsing image format (bgr8), using default Ogre::PF_BYTE_RGB
```

It is publishing images with encoding field set to sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8 no matter what, while the actual encoding is BGR8.

How can I fix this? I would like to use the same node in Gazebo and on the robot without additional workaround.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32450/gazebo-image-topic-encoding/) by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The available `image_format` values for gazebo are `R8G8B8`, `B8G8R8`, `BAYER_RGGB8`, `BAYER_BGGR8`, `BAYER_GBRG8` and `BAYER_GRBG8`.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__camera__utils_8cpp_source.html

there is also "L8" for monochrome images

---

Originally posted by [shaviland3](https://answers.ros.org/users/27267/shaviland3/) with karma: 11 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1